# How to switch user profile based on password / lockscreen pattern

Tags: lock-screens, 4.2-jelly-bean, password, profiles, multi-user

Currently, I have a family use tablet running on 4.2 Jellybean

Model is [Ainol Novo7 Flame](http://www.ainol-novo.com/ainol-novo-7-flame-dual-core-1-5ghz-7-inch-1280-800-ips-screen-android-tablet.html), a cheap Nexus7 alternative. Nexus7 is quite expensive in my country on its release so I bought this one instead.

The problem is that the tablet is shared. I already set-up multi-user profiles for each of us.

1. Family mode
2. My mode
3. My sister's mode

The default user set is family but I want it to automatically switch user-profiles based on the entered password or pattern lock.

example: password `1358` triggers `My mode` while entering `2467` triggers `My sister's mode` profile

I would also like to have an option to lock certain apps automatically when in `family mode` but unlocked in `My mode`

Is there a way to do this? or is there an app that can closely do some of it?

Comment: I wonder if some combination of Titanium Backup, Tasker, and Secure Settings would do the trick. I'm posting as a comment instead of an answer because this is an untested wild guess.

Comment: I havent used tasker yet. I might as well try it and see if it can mimic some actions. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: Tasker cannot get the typed password, it only detects lockscreen state. Question still open for answers.

Comment: there is also a thread on XDA
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2363535 Link to feature request of cyano
https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-984

Comment: Yes, You can get these facility in all vivo model as per your requirenent, means mode of entry in to the phone is depend on given password or pettern lock,,, its happen only in vivo mobile,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure automatic password detection is available. After all, computers don't really have that function. You still have to select the user/enter username.

As far as having the option to lock certain apps automatically when in family mode but unlocked in My mode, upgrade your Android version at least 4.3 (newest is Lollipop 5.0 but that's not available across all devices yet- 4.4.4 KitKat is widely available).

This will give you access to a new profile/user type: **Restricted Profiles**.

From [Google's help pages](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3175031?hl=en):
About restricted profiles

> As the tablet owner, you can create restricted profiles that limit the
>   access that others have to features and content on your tablet. For
>   example, you can create restricted profiles to prevent family members
>   who may have access to your tablet from viewing mature content.
>
> You can use restricted profiles for several purposes, including these:
>
> - Parental controls. Selectively restrict family members from accessing mature content.
> - Kiosk. Set up the tablet to demonstrate selected apps and features to customers.
> - Retail. Let customers explore tablet features, but prevent them from    browsing or playing games.
> - Point of sale. Limit employees to the use of selected sales and register apps.

To set up a restricted profile:

> Note: You must be the tablet owner to create a restricted profile.
>
> 1. Touch Settings  > Users > Add user or profile.
> 2. Touch Restricted profile, and the new profile with a list of settings displays. To name the profile, touch New profile.
> 3. Using the ON/OFF toggles and Settings , select the features and settings you want to grant access to.
>
> To set up the new profile, press the Power button to return to the
>   lock screen, then touch the new profile icon.
>
> When the restricted user finishes setting up, the Home screen is
>   empty. The granted apps appear after the user touches the All Apps
>   icon .
>
> **Edit a restricted profile**
>
> Note: You must be the tablet owner to edit a restricted profile.
>
> 1. Touch Settings  > Users.
> 2. Touch the profile icon.
> 3. Using the ON/OFF toggles and Settings , select the features and settings you want to grant or deny. The changes take place in real time.
>
> Important: If you turn off an app, the profile user loses all content
>   associated with that app. If you grant access again, the content isn’t
>   restored.