# Switch Between 2 profiles on android during device unlock

Tags: profiles, restricted-profiles

I have 2 profiles setup on my device as shown here

https://www.howtogeek.com/333484/how-to-set-up-multiple-user-profiles-on-android/

However the switching of accounts as shown here is cumbersome. Is there any app/ approach where I can enter something to unlock phone(separate pin) that will load the profiles appropriately.I sometimes hand over my phone to family and don't and switching profiles after unlocking takes too long.

Comment: This is an unsolved problem. See [How to switch user profile based on password / lockscreen pattern](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40599)