# Android hidden account

Tags: applications, security, launcher

Is there any way to create hidden account in Android as it described in Cory Doctorow book "Little Brother"? When I enter pin code like 1234 this will open first account. When I enter 5678 this will open second. Is there any launcher with this feature?

Comment: Duplicate of: [How to switch user profile based on password / lockscreen pattern](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40599/3573) and referenced in this thread: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-switch-user-profile-based-on-password-lockscreen-pattern.3895406/ but most likely only possible with root/Custom ROM.