# Hide main ui/launcher/profile on specific password

Tags: security, lock-screens, password, multi-user

I'd like to have an option to hide my usual apps list, photos, etc on specific pass unlock.
So if I unlock with my usual pass - it is my usual device, if someone requires to unlock my device - I use another pass, it unlocks device but with hidden sensitive data.

We assume there is no option to connect adb on that check (just on the street).

Is it possible? Maybe some launcher or even firmware. I'm ok to root device if needed.

Comment: Kind of related: [How to switch user profile based on password / lockscreen pattern](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40599/44325).

Comment: Thank you! I saw that topic. It is related but not exactly what needed.