# Typing other password to start other Android launcher

Tags: password, launcher, multi-user

On an android 8 phone, I would like to be able to open a different launcher (or user session) depending on the password that I type (or the pattern that I draw).

Example :

- when I type "real_password123", my phone opens with all the usual apps and documents.
- when I type "fake_password123", my phone opens and shows only a selection of apps and hides documents. But it is not visible that the current session is a fake one.

Usecase : If relatives or authorities put pressure on you to reveal your phone password, you may want to give in, and still protect your privacy.

Tried so far :
The Automate automation app that has a "When login failed" event, which can be used for instance to take a picture when the wrong password is given; but I can't get it to start an alternative launcher or session.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. This is a long outstanding problem: [How to switch user profile based on password / lockscreen pattern](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40599/44325).

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the problem is to use something like parallel space. It allows you to run clone versions of apps.

Install, configure and use sensitive apps inside there. On login, the user will see the normal space only. When required, you run parallel space and use the sensitive apps.

1. Make sure you don't leave a shortcut for parallel space on your home screen. And put a password on it.
2. Using an automate style app to run parallel space automatically for all users, wont work, because you can always access normal space.