# Android multi-user - switch users from lockscreen based on solely on PIN or biometrics

Tags: xiaomi, multi-user, miui

Xiaomi and its sub-brands run an Android skin called MIUI (recently updated to HyperOS). MIUI/HyperOS has a feature called Second Space. This is an excellent feature, it is like you have two completely separate phones in one device.

I believe that Xiaomi Second Space feature is an impllementation of AOSP Android multi-user functionality.
The unique aspect of Xiaomi's implementation is that the phone will launch one or the other of the "spaces" from the lock screen, based SOLELY on the PIN of fingerprint used for authentication on the lock screen. I.e., there is no need to select one or the other space (user) before authenticating to the selected space. It knows which space you want to go to, based on your authentication.
This is an incredibly convenient feature.

I have played with bare Android multi-user functionality on and older vesion of Android (Pixel 3, Android 12). The multi-user implelentation is clunky. The clunkiness is best described by example. I will use the terms User1 for the main user and User2 for the subsequently-created second user profile.

Suppose I sign in as User1, then lock the phone. I now want to sign in as User2.

With my Xiaomi, I can do this by simply entering the PIN for User2 on the lock screen.

With the Pixel 3 / Android 12, the process is as follows:
Remember that my last sign-in was a User1.
Enter the PIN for User1. (If I try entering the PIN for User2, it tells me wrong PIN).
Pull down the shade to select User2.
Enter the PIN for user2.

My question is this:
Are there any other Android phone brands the allow simple switching between users based SOLELY on authentication credentials, without first having to select the user you want to authenticate as?

Comment: Related: [How to switch user profile based on password / lockscreen pattern](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40599/44325), a comment mentioned "vivo mobile". AFAIK, this is a very niche feature in Android.